# Display Image based on URL GET

Tags: php, image, get

Im sure this is simple but newbie here.

I have 5 URLS

```
cards.php&type=one
cards.php&type=two
cards.php&type=three
cards.php&type=four
```

Question.

**How will I display an image based on the URL**

```
Image Directory = images/cards/one.jpg,two.jpg etc...
```

Thanks your help is much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$type = $_REQUEST['type'];
    if($type == "one")
    {
      $imag = "images/cards/one.jpg";
    }
    else if($type == "two")
    {
      $imag = "images/cards/two.jpg";
    }......
```

or use

```
switch ($type)
{
case one:
  $imag = "images/cards/one.jpg";
  break;
case two:
  $imag = "images/cards/two.jpg";
  break;
case three:
  $imag = "images/cards/three.jpg";
  break;
default:
  $imag = "images/cards/default.jpg";
}
```

try this one i think it might help you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
echo "<img src='{$_GET['type']}.jpg' />";
```

And with a check:

```
if (isset($_GET['type']) && (trim($_GET['type']) != "")) {
   echo "<img src='". $_GET['type'] .".jpg";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of, the delimiter between the "hier-part" and the query string is `?`, not `&`, cf. [RFC 3986 - Uniform Resource Identifier (URI): Generic Syntax](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3). Your URLs should thus look like:

```
cards.php?type=one
cards.php?type=two
cards.php?type=three
cards.php?type=four
```

Now, inspect the contents of the global `$_GET` array using e.g. `print_r($_GET)`. You should find an entry with the key `type` corresponding with the query string parameter.

Next, use the value of `type` (`$_GET['type']`) to write an image tag. Beware that users can easily manipulate the query string so some input sanitation should be performed.